# How to translate list to integers with python

Tags: python

How i can translate following list to integers?

```
g_weeks = ['platform', 'week 47', 'week 48', 'week 49', 'week 50']
```

I try followings:

```
weeks = [int(w) for w in g_weeks]
```

but returns me valueerror

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'platform'
```

Comment: `platform` is an integer?!?

Comment: What do you want the result to be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you are after:

```
g_weeks =  ['platform', 'week 47', 'week 48', 'week 49', 'week 50']

nums = []
for week in g_weeks:
    words = week.split()
    try:
        nums.append(int(words[-1]))
    except ValueError:
        pass

print nums  -- [47, 48, 49, 50]
```

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
weeks = []
for week in g_weeks:
    try:
        weeks.append(int(week[-2:]))
    except ValueError:
        pass
```

then you can `print(weeks)` or whatever you need to do with it.

Comment: returning:
`TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str`

Comment: Did you mean `[-2:]`?

Comment: Urgh typoed again, yes I meant `[-2:]`, fixed